# How is this site different than StackOverflow

Tags: discussion, stackoverflow

The purpose of this site is presumably to help professional programmers with programming tasks they encounter in the course of their work. Both sites contain code examples, so that doesn't seem to be the differentiating characteristic. Could someone please explain why this is not a "duplicate" site?

Comment: Read the [about] page and the [help/on-topic] of both sites. Though there is **some** overlap, they have different scopes and intended audiences.

Comment: `It breaked now and I changed nothing. Please send me teh codez!!` never goes well here but it is sometimes successful on StackOverflow